# Difference between eucKR and UTF-8 Encoding?

Tags: qt, unix

What is Difference between eucKR and UTF-8 Encoding in QT ?
I want to display Korean Language which one to use ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> Qt uses Unicode to store, draw and manipulate strings.

From this I understand that Qt 'talks' Unicode - all other character sets are converted to Unicode with the aid of Qt's Text Codec system. I believe the same underlying system is used for standard text Widgets as well as other parts of the framework, e.g. QtWebKit.

The conversion system is directly exposed to the user in [`QTextCodec`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html), which provides (among other things) [a codec for EUC-KR](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/codec-euckr.html).

Converting EUC-KR to Unicode should therefore be as simple as:

```
QByteArray encodedString = "...";
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("EUC-KR");
QString string = codec->toUnicode(encodedString);
```

Comment: UTF-8, You can use it for any language, even many languages at once, you don't have to worry about managing multiple encodings. Then why it is required to convert to "EUC-KR"

Comment: Exactly: Unicode is capable of representing any and all characters, which is why Qt uses it. EUC-KR is a way of representing Korean characters which happens to still be popular in Korea, hence Qt provides a method to convert from the EUC-KR data (as provided by yourself or by the user) to the equivalent Unicode data (as understood by Qt and presumably the display font).